# How to suppress quotes output as HTML entities?

Tags: html, perl, escaping, quotes

```
$selected = ' selected="selected"'
# or
$selected = qq( selected="selected")
```

is returned as:

```
selected=&quot;selected&quot;
```

which is an invalid HTML attribute, ofcourse.

How do I fix it?

Edited to add:

```
<select name="alignment" class="select" 
    <%== param('feature') ? '' : 'disabled'; %>
>
% foreach (keys %al) {
%  my $selected = param('aligment') && param('aligment') eq $_ ? ' selected' : '';
%
%  if (!param('aligment') && $_ eq 'left') { $selected = ' selected' }
%
    <option value="<%=$_%>" <%= $selected %>>
     <%= $al{$_} %>
    </option>
%        
% }
</select>
```

Thanks!

Comment: Are you using some kind of HTML::Entities ?

Comment: Ummm yes probably, but I'm the designer, not the developer and can't fix anything at the backend.

Comment: I can't see how to fix it without going in the code.

Comment: I searched for "HTML::Entities" in the code, found nothing.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

according to Mojolicious web framework documents you would need to add and extra = at <%= in order to print it in raw format.

```
<%= $selected %>
```

would be

```
<%== $selected %>
```

for more reference you can read this http://github.com/kraih/mojo/blob/master/lib/Mojolicious/Guides/Rendering.pod

try like this:

```
<select name="alignment" class="select" 
    <%== param('feature') ? '' : 'disabled'; %>
>
% foreach (keys %al) {
%  my $selected = param('aligment') && param('aligment') eq $_ ? ' selected' : '';
%
%  if (!param('aligment') && $_ eq 'left') { $selected = ' selected' }
%
<option value="<%=$_%>"
 <%= $selected %>
>
     <%= $al{$_} %>
    </option>
%        
% }
</select>
```

or

```
<select name="alignment" class="select" 
    <%== param('feature') ? '' : 'disabled'; %>
>
% foreach (keys %al) {
%  my $selected = param('aligment') && param('aligment') eq $_ ? ' selected="selected"' : '';
%
%  if (!param('aligment') && $_ eq 'left') { $selected = ' selected="selected"' }
%
<option value="<%=$_%>"
 <%== $selected %>
>
     <%= $al{$_} %>
    </option>
%        
% }
</select>
```

Comment: Edited my question to include the relevant portion of the code.

Comment: It seems youre using a module like Toolkit or so, can you post what is in the top of your code the "use CGI;" etc...

Comment: Yes, its based on Mojolicious web framework. Found no instances of "use CGI" in the whole code.

Comment: Awesome!! :) Just one thing though, it doesn't print the ending '>' of the option tag, so its <option value="default"  selected="selected" instead of <option value="default"  selected="selected">

Comment: try putting a space between >> to look like > > i am not experienced with this framework at all that was all the information i could find but it might be a bug perhaps ? finalizing the %> with an extra > might get read all together ...

Comment: I am wondering, inst there an option for the html option like you have for input ? <%= input 'test', type => 'text' %> so you would go like <%= option $_, selected => true %> or something alike, but since the documentation was very limited i would need to acutally look into the .pm files to figure it out ...

Comment: `$selected = ' selected=\"selected\"'`
and then `<option value="<%=$_%>" <%== $selected %> >` doesn't seem to fix it. Hmm...

Comment: you dont need to scape the " you are already using single quote also, it just run thru my mind the correct HTML code for a selected option in a dropdown is selected only and not selected="selected" ... Looking at your code posted above check your select, the ending > is on the next line instead of next to it, try doing it like that...

Comment: `"selected"` or `selected="selected"` (either is valid) but the problem is using either of those doesn't close the ending > of the the option tag. Tried putting the ending > on new line.

Comment: I started all over again and somehow its fixed. Strange, but good for me. :) BTW, if you're a perl expert and familiar with mojolicious framework and if you're interested in assisting me, professionally, with this (skinning a single-page tiny perl app), please let me know your email so we can talk. its nearly done but the last few things are taking hours cause I know nothing about perl. Thanks!

Comment: i am sorry, my experience with mojolicious is near 0, first time i  heard of it was when you mentioned it so i went to take a look at it to see how good it was... usually i do my own stuff from scratch using C::APP and H::Template and tune it to my needs. Glad you got it fixed.

Comment: I don't think you need to know mojolicious to skin the app, its mainly html with perl code in between, and the app itself is too simple small, just one-page (at the frontend). no?

Comment: well you need to know all the rendering and the options you have available within it, and everything, from what i saw ... but if u have any questions you can drop a pm here with the link and i will try to help you what with what i can no problem ;)

Comment: There's no PM functionality on SO, can we talk on gTalk?

Comment: i meant, if you send a PM in this Question i will get notified and if u reply with another question link, i will be able to check it and help you out with what i can :)